# Can I limit the size of rsync transfer based on the size of delta?

Tags: bash, rsync

Is there a way to limit the size of deltas that `rsync` will transfer?

I'm aware of the `--max-size` option, but that filters out entire files based on the size of the file. This could mean that if I have a growing file, it will stop being synced once it exceeds the file size limit.

I'd prefer to be able to specify a limit on the amount of data to be transferred. So that a file will stop being synced if it has grown more than the defined limit.

The only thing I can think of is to write a file list with sizes on each transfer, and compare the new file sizes, to create an exclude list if a file has exceeded the transfer limit. This seems like far too much overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The correct way to do this is to use `--files-from` and an external script, as you describe.

Alternatively, you might also like to experiment with "batch mode" (using `--only-write-batch`/`--read-batch`), in which case you could choose to cancel the sync if the batch-file is oversized.